# How can an empty for(;;) work?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

How does an empty for works?

I have seen this code (and works perfectly)

```
for(;;) {
```

And I can't comprehend how is this working or why

Comment: C++ is full of special strange rules... this is just one of them.

Comment: Read it like this: `for nothing, until no condition, and nothing changes`. Logically that would be `true` always. And hence it's an endless loop.

Comment: @6502 - there's nothing special here. It just falls out from the way `for` is defined.

Comment: @PeteBecker: exactly... and for example I can write `while()` too or use `if()` to mean an always-true condition. Not.

Comment: @6502 - yes, the specifications for `if` and `while` are different from the specification for `for`. Since they do very different things, that is neither "special" nor "strange".

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly like `while(true)`. 
It skips all the conditions so it just empty-executes since in `for` the expressions are all optional (i.e. you don't have to provide them if you choose not to).